# Choosing the appropriate power plug for a given fan motor

Tags: electricity, electrical

In a fan motor I have, the written specifications are as follow :

"dual power: 110/230v 50/60Hz 22/20w".

I would like to power the motor directly, without electronic parts between any 220V wall power socket and the motor ( only a standard power plug unit). 
To select the appropriate 220v power plug I need to know the amperage.

Using the formula A=w(20)/V(230), I get A=0.0869

1. Are my calculations correct ?
2. If they are, then I am lost. What kind of power plug could I use to get such a low amperage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plug only needs to support an amperage *equal to or greater than* your device requires. A plug that supports excessive amperage will not cause any issues.

Comment: Is is true for any other case for the selection of a power plug ?

Comment: I would add that even though @Sam will be powering the fan at 220 V, he should consider the worst case that someone may switch the fan to 110 V and expect the plug to be adequate (should make no difference in this case since it'll still be a small 0.2 A current draw).

Comment: And I partially disagree with you last sentence since using a plug that supports excessive amperage could make @Sam end up with a heavy duty high power plug that expects thick wires. So, the possibly thin fan wires could make for a bad connection with the plug's terminals and get little support from the plug's casing.

Comment: So to clarify, more amperage isn't a problem but a too large up-difference would require new considerations. Thank you guys!

Comment: The plug may be bigger than necessary, and that could be inconvenient but there won't be any safety issues.